# Single writer and multiple readers for a map

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap

I have a use case where there is a single writer that is writing to a map that will contain some reference data. This map is hydrated at the beginning of an application after which its guaranteed to never be modified.

I have multiple threads that would be reading this map after the intial hydration is done. Are there are things that I should keep in mind to make sure that I don't run into any race conditions here?

I already have a blocking queue in my app that helps route requests to various threads and each caller gets back a future that they can use to read the result. I was wondering if it's necessary to follow the same thing for accessing this map or I could just pass a reference to the map to all the threads for direct access since they would only be reading it.

Based on the comments by @ControlAltDel and @SolomonSlow I think the following should do what I need

Foo.java

```
public class Foo {
  private final String f1;
  private final Integer f2;
  public Foo(String f1, Integer f2) {
     this.f1 = f1;
     this.f2 = f2;
  }
  //hashcode, toString, equals go here
}
```

MySpringAppConfiguration.java

```
public class MySpringAppConfiguration {
@Bean
public Map<String, Foo> fooMapping() {
  return new HashMap<>();
}

@Bean
public Writer writer() {
  return new Writer(fooMapping());
}

@Bean
public ReaderWorker1 reader1() {
  return new ReaderWorker1(Collections.unmodifiableMap(fooMapping()));
}
//other reader types defined here
}
```

ReaderWorker1.java

```
public class ReaderWorker1 {
private final Map<String, Foo> fooMapping;

public ReaderWorker(Map<String, Foo> fooMapping) {
  this.fooMapping = fooMapping;
}

//reader logic
}
```

Writer.java

```
public class Writer {
private final Map<String, Foo> fooMapping;

public Writer(Map<String, Foo> fooMapping) {
  this.fooMapping = fooMapping;
}
}
```

Comment: It is safe to pass an *immutable* reference to the map to all threads: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap-java.util.Map-

Comment: If there are no writers once the map is constructed, you don't need to synchronize the reads.

Comment: @ControlAltDel my app is a SpringBoot application and I am injecting the map in all the reader classes. I am not sure if that would work. Is there a pattern you would recommend to fit this in?

Comment: @harshvardhan.agr if you don't try it, you'll never know

Comment: @ControlAltDel, If the OP _does_ try it, then they still won't know. Verifying a multi-threaded application by trial and error is not wise.

Comment: @harshvardhan.agr, When want to share an immutable (or _effectively_ immutable) data structure between threads, then you'll want to make sure that you [_safely publish_ it](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/).

Comment: @SolomonSlow thanks for the article. It was super useful. I think the following should work fine;
I have a `Map<String, Foo>` that I am initializing inside a Spring Bean definition. All fields in Foo are `final` which would guarantee safe initialization. This map is injected into all the reader classes using Spring which gives me the Singleton I want and stored in a `final` field in those classes. Once the writer is done hydrating this map, the readers should see a consistent copy of Foo when they try to read it.